# What is wrong with my approach?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Q) There are 2k+1 people sitting around a circular table , let them be $P_1,P_2,...,P_{2k+1}. P_1$ is sitting between $P_2$ and $P_{2k+1}.P_2$ sitting between ${P_1}$ and ${P_3}$ and so on.Find the number of ways to select **non empty** subset of these people, such that no two adjacent people are selected.The subset can be of any size.
>   For e.g. :
>  
>   For k=2, the possible groups are (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4)(2,5),(3,5) and no more subsets with 3 or more elements are possible.

My Approach: Let the even no. be selected and space are represented as _.Therefore, sequence now:
_2_4_6_8_10_12......2k-2_2k_. The dashes are to be filled with odd numbers(except 2k+1 as 1 and 2k+1 are sitting together) such that (1,3) don't come with 2 or (3,5) don't come with 5 and so on (so as consecutive elements are not selected). So the first dash is filled with any of k-1 elements,second with k-1 elements and total ways is k-2 * k-2 * k-2 * k-3 * ..... *1 elements. Add the same, as it is done by taking 2k+1 as an element instead of 1 and the total cases now(including both): 2 * k-2 * k-2 * k-2 * ..... *1. I did the same and added them by reducing it the sizes of elements,and I am unable to reach the correct answer with this.What is wrong with this approach? Also is there a shorter way to do the question?

> Correct answers:
>   For k=5;  **number of such sets = 198**
>   For k=6;**number of such sets=520**
>   For k=7;**number of such sets=1363**

Comment: Your approach doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "first dash can be filled with 2k-2 elements"? Can't it only be filled with 1 (or maybe 2)?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong information. What I mean was choose k-2. Basically, after not taking 2k+1 with the numbers and making it as a separate case, there are k odd numbers left. Out of those,(1,3) can't occupy the first space as they are together with 2,leaving k-2 numbers which can be put into the first dash? It is just one dash BUT it can be filled with numbers like 5,7,9......,

Comment: So can the first dash be filled with 9, and the second dash be filled with 8?

Comment: Let me rephrase. I was trying to point out an issue with your approach. How does your method prevent the first dash to be filled with 9, and the second dashto be filled with 8? It seems to me that "1, 2, 3" can not be in the first dash so we can choose 9, and then "3, 4, 5, 9" can not be in the second dash so we can choose 8.

Comment: Yes, but isn't there 2 in between the two dashes? Therefore, making 928 as legal combination and only illegal combinations (for the first 3) to be 123 or 321 or 32x or 12x or x21 or x23 (x is any other number). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is the question asking to "Arrange all n people around the table so that no 2 people sitting next to each other have consecutive index" or "Select some people so that no 2 selected people have consecutive index"? Your comment indicates the former, the question (as well as the answers) suggests the latter.

Comment: Okay,I get it. I have clearly misunderstood the question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** It is easier to solve the problem by recurrence for all $n$, not just odd number of people.

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to select these people with the above conditions.

Show that $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + 1$ for $n\geq 4$. The +1 follows because we have to choose **non-empty** people.

Clearly we have $a_2 = 2, a_3 = 3$. From here, we can find that $a_{11} = 198, a_{13} = 520, a_{15} = 1363.$

---

Let $L_n$ be the number of ways to select $n$ people in a line, no 2 consecutive. We allow for possibly selecting 0 people.

We want to create a recurrence relation for $L_n$.
Let's consider the cases where person 1 is selected. Person 2 cannot be selected, and persons 3 to $n$ just have to obey the "no 2 consecutive" rule, so there are $L_{n-2}$ ways to select them.
Let's consider the cases where person 1 is not selected. Persons 2 to $n$ just have to obey the "no 2 consecutive" rule, so there are $L_{n-1}$ ways to select them.
Hence, we can conclude that:

$$L_n = L_{n-2} + L_{n-1} $$

Let $C_n$ be the number of ways to select $n$ people in a circle, no 2 consecutive. We allow for possibly selecting 0 people.
By conditioning on whether 1 is selected or not, we have

$$ \begin{array} {l l } C_n & = L_{n-3} + L_{n-1} \\ 
& = L_{n-4} + L_{n-5} + L_{n-2} + L_{n-3} \\
& = C_{n-1} + C_{n-2} \end{array}$$

Clearly $a_n = C_n - 1 $. So $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + 1$

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how to show an = an-1 + an-2 +1? Did you get it by putting the values and seeing the trend?I tried first taking n elements, and then n-1 but I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: @TheQuestioner I've added details.

Comment: I am going to be honest, I have no idea what you did above. How did Ln-2 and Ln-1 come if you are selecting n-1 and n people respectively from above. Also why did you declare Cn, which is same as Ln, and how did you get the relation. Why did you make 2 cases one including the 1 and other excluding it.And above all how did you know it will work?. I did try searching and reading about "combinatorics recursion" but still can't find meaning behind the answer.Can you please explain or give link to any article like this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TheQuestioner I've added details of how to set up the recurrence relation for $L_n$. If that is clear, try to figure out how the $C_n$ case is done.

Comment: I do get what you have done with ln but i don't get why. Why is the condition that 1 is selected and other case as 1 not being selected?Also aren't cn and ln representing the same thing ie number of ways to select n people in a line, no 2 consecutive?Why are they different in terms of Ln?

Comment: 1) That's a useful way/trick to consider cases to build recurrence relations. 2) Sorry, changed $C_n$ to circle (as it was meant to be).

Comment: I finally got the answer and the method.However, I saw this approach for the first time. Any books or articles or webpage I should read to learn more about it and in which kind of problems this approach can be used?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we can “flatten” the table to a row, and then throw away the bad choices. We have this result:

> (Key Step) There are $n$ people sitting in a **row**. The number of ways to choose $m$ people from $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_n$ with no consecutive people chosen is $\binom{n-m+1}{m}$

Now we can just remove the “bad” ones, which is when $P_1$ sits with $P_n$

> There are $n$ people sitting in a **round table**. The number of ways to choose $m$ people from $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_n$ with no consecutive people chosen is $\binom{n-m+1}{m}-\binom{n-m-1}{m}$

Now you can just sum from $m=1$ to $m=k$ with $n=2k+1$.

The difficulty from this problem comes from (Key Step), but I think it’s quite a well known combinatorial problem